# знак меню не изменяется

Tags: java, android

Всем привет,создал меню добавил там должна отображатся иконка обновления и при нажатии крутится прогресс бар,делал раньше получалось ,может устал чтото от глаза сбежал )Знак не меняется и при нажатии на знак меню ниче не происходит  а вот и сами разметки внизку

это menu_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:title="Item"
        android:id="@+id/action_progress_show"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_white_36dp"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

это поргресс бар

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

а это мой MainActivity:

```html
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     Menu mymenu;
        MenuItem progress_menu_item; Menu mymenu;
        MenuItem progress_menu_item;

    ...

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

            mymenu = menu;
            progress_menu_item = mymenu.findItem(R.id.action_progress_show);


            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_progress_show) {
                progress_menu_item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_layout);

                  return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Возможно это у вас `InstantRun` глючит

Comment: стоит на девайсе проверить?

Comment: Проверил на Раннере проблем нет ... чтото гдето недописал судя пойду копаться далше

Comment: Я вас не понял - на девайсе проблем нет? Проблема решена?

Comment: Научитесь уже форматировать код

Comment: И кстати - зачем вы так код выделяете?

Comment: Проблема актуальна )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему добавление ссылки в `main_menu.xml`

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: Т.е. проблема у вас была не в том, что на устройстве/эмуляторе не работает, а в том, что в предпросмотрорщике студии не работало? Если да, то вот вам совет - никогда его не используйте - с ним больше проблем чем пользы.

Comment: да Юрий с вами полностью согласен ... Да вобще как по мне А-Студио очень карявая.Ищу ей замену не подскажите что ?МОжет InteljDea?

Comment: @elik, Android Studio – это самая качественная и актуальная IDE для разработки под Android.

Comment: Ну я не спорю с этим просто часто несостыковок у нее много .её эмуляторы не корреткно отображают WebView окей начал тестить на девайсе

Comment: У нее часто проблемы с дебагом .и руннером глючит кстати

Comment: Предсмотрщик почти в 90 % слачаев кроме лнера с детскими ячейками толком ниче не отображает загрузи билиотеку и сразу даст рендринга и много такого по мелочей в сумме это все дискомофрт

Comment: окей у нее есть авто текст и какието + плагины отображения формулы так это можно и на другии платформы добавить ну незнаю @post_zeew учту твое мнение обезательно

Comment: @elik, `WebView` – сама по себе глючная вещь, и Android Studio тут не при чем. `Instant Run` – это очень сложная штука, из-за которой порой что-то работает некорректно (но Google при этом про эти вещи сам пишет). А насчет IDE – Вы просто не найдете другую. Плагины под Eclipse и Intellij IDEA уже давно не поддерживаются.

Comment: @post_zeew Поняяятненько)Ну спасибо за совет ,благодарен !)